# Foundation Block Grid small not working

Tags: css, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I have the following React component in which I try to load a series of divs onto the page using the Foundation Block Grid system to limit the number of divs per row. Currently for some reason the number of divs per row does change from 6 to 4 when I switch from a large screen to a medium screen, but the number of divs does not change when I switch to a small sized screen.

Does anyone know why the small-up 1 class that the bottom is not taking effect when I switch to a small screen?

Thank you.

```
const MovieList = ({movies}) => {
  if (movies.length === 0) {
    return <p>We Could Not Find Anything</p>;
  }
  movies = movies.map((movie) => {
    let className = "column column-block movie-box";
    let image;
    if (movie.poster_path) {
      image = <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${movie.poster_path}`} />;
    } else {
      image = <img src={`http://www.planetvlog.com/wp-content/themes/betube/assets/images/watchmovies.png`} />;
    }

    return(
      <div key={movie.id} className={className}>
        <p>{movie.title}</p>
        {image}
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className='row small-up-1 medium-up-4 large-up-6'>
      {movies}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply row and column classes to the same div. Also, it's `class`, not `className`.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='small-up-1 medium-up-4 large-up-6'>
        {movies}
    </div>
</div>
```